# Converting xml files with xml fo to pdf using C# and fonet library

Tags: c#, xml, pdf

Hello I am having a problem with my program when I am using the fonet library for c#. I am trying to generate a pdf file using the xml fo to generate it while using fonet library in .NET framwork or .NET core.

My C# code is as follows:

```
var driver = FonetDriver.Make();
driver.Render(pathFo, pathPDF);
```

And my xml fo code is:

```xml
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<fo:layout-master-set master-name="A4" page-width="297mm" height="210mm"
                      margin-top="1cm" margin-bottom="1cm" left="1cm" margin-right="1cm">
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4">
  <fo:region-body flow-name="xsl-region-body" margin="3cm"/>
  <fo:region-before extent="2cm"/>
  <fo:region-after extent="2cm"/>
  <fo:region-start extent="2cm"/>
  <fo:region-end extent="2cm"/>
  </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>

<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
  <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
    <fo:block font-family="Helvetica" font-size=“36pt"
    text-align="end“space-after="36pt">
    Hello world!
    </fo:block> 
  </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

It throws an exception Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\rendered.pdf' is denied.

I already tried giving all the premissions to my disk and folders and what confuses me that any other file can be created / written / read with the program just the pdf ones are causing me problems.
If anyone can help me with this it would be much appriciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have found the answer myself. If anyone get this problem it can be resovled with removing non-english characters in the path of the pdf such as "č,ć,ž" in my language.
Hope this can help somebody.